# SignalR OnDisconnected event not persisting data to DB

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, castle-windsor

I have a SignalR hub in which I'm injecting service classes which persist data to a local SQL Server instance via Castle Windsor.

The hub looks like:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyHub : Hub 
{
    private readonly IHubService _hubService;
    private readonly IHubUserService _hubUserService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public MyHub(IHubService hubService, IHubUserService hubUserService, IUserService userService)
    {
        _hubService = hubService;
        _hubUserService = hubUserService;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task JoinHub(Guid hubId) 
    {
        var hub = _hubService.GetHubById(hubId);

        if (hub == null)
            throw new NotFoundException(String.Format("Hub ({0}) was not found.", hubId.ToString()));

        var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        var user = _userService.GetUserByUserName(userName);

        if (user == null)
            throw new NotFoundException(String.Format("User ({0}) was not found.", userName));

        var hubUser = new HubUser
        {
            User = user,
            Hub = hub,
            ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId
        };

        // Persist a new HubUser to the DB
        hubUser = _hubUserService.InsertHubUser(hubUser);

        await Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, hub.Id.ToString());
        Clients.Group(hub.Id.ToString()).addChatMessage(userName + " has joined.");
    }

    public async Task LeaveHub()
    {
        var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        var hubUser = _hubUserService.GetHubUserByUserName(userName);

        // Removes HubUser from the DB
        _hubUserService.RemoveHubUser(hubUser);

        await Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, hubUser.Hub.Id.ToString());
        Clients.Group(hubUser.Hub.Id.ToString()).addChatMessage(userName + " has left.");
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        var hubUser = _hubUserService.GetHubUserByUserName(userName);

        // Removes HubUser from the DB
        _hubUserService.RemoveHubUser(hubUser); // This line executes but does not persist anything to DB

        Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, hubUser.Hub.Id.ToString());
        Clients.Group(hubUser.Hub.Id.ToString()).addChatMessage(userName + " has left.");
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
}
```

When calling JoinHub and LeaveHub methods from the client, everything works fine. However, when the OnDisconnected method fires, nothing is deleted from the database. I can see that the code does indeed execute, but the record remains in the DB and does not get deleted.

I'm wondering if perhaps my nhibernate session is not committing the transaction to the database due to castle windsor's dependency lifetimes or something, however, it's odd that LeaveHub executes as expected but the same code does not in the OnDisconnected method.

My dependencies are registered with the following configuration as per [this](http://www.leniel.net/2013/01/signalr-ondisconnected-task-and-dependency-injection-with-castle.windsor-hybrid-lifestyle.html#sthash.lyjhRLIJ.dpbs) blog post.

```
Kernel.Register(
    //Nhibernate session factory
    Component.For<ISessionFactory>().UsingFactoryMethod(CreateNhSessionFactory).LifeStyle.Singleton,

    //Nhibernate session
    Component.For<ISession>().UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient()
);
```

and I also register an interceptor to implement a unit of work pattern:

```
// Unitofwork interceptor
Component.For<NhUnitOfWorkInterceptor>().LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient()
```

If anyone can give any input on why the method LeaveHub works correctly and why it fails to persist anything in the OnDisconnected method, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm just guessing as I don't have enough context, but since you are using task are you sure that OnDisconnected is completed before the UnitOfWork is released.

Comment: I don't believe OnDisconnected is completed before the UnitOfWork is released. The interceptor intercepts all methods at the repository level, so the UnitOfWork starts and finishes inside OnDisconnected at my service call `_hubUserService.RemoveHubUser(hubUser);`

Comment: I believe in your interceptor implementation you have somwhere something like commit of current trunsaction? Could you place breakepoint there? And maybe look what's going on in Sql profiler?

Comment: I can see the transaction committing when I expect it. I will try and use NHibernate Profiler to dig a bit deeper. In the logs NHibernate is not executing any queries during the OnDisconnected method. I believe it's probably something with how I'm managing the session.

Answer (score 2):

Just an FYI Nhibernate Sessions don't do so well using async as they are not threadsafe at all. Try running things synchronously and see what you get.

Is Nhibernate set to flush on transaction commit? I can't comment becasue I am a newbie but I ran into this issue some time ago. I am not using FluentNhibernate but I am sure there is a config option to set flush on transaction commit. This is assuming you are wrapping all open session calls in a transaction. I use something like this for sessions. Also go get Nhibernate Profiler it is a godsend.

```
 public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private ISession _currentSession;
    private ITransaction _currentTransaction;

    public SessionManager(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public ISession OpenSession()
    {
        if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(_sessionFactory))
        {
            _currentSession = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
        }
        else
        {
            _currentSession = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_currentSession);
        }
        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(_currentSession);
        _currentTransaction = _currentSession.BeginTransaction();
        return _currentSession;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            if (_currentTransaction != null && _currentTransaction.IsActive)
                _currentTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            if (_currentTransaction != null) _currentTransaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_currentSession != null)
            {
                if (_currentTransaction != null) _currentTransaction.Dispose();
                _currentSession.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my configuration, I am using it on several apps. On a side not there is a reason I don't use FluentNhibernate, The mapping by code built in is awesome and flexible. Let me know I can send you some sample mappings.

```
  public class SessionFactoryBuilder
{
    public static ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(string connectionString)
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
        {
            db.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
            db.Driver<Sql2008ClientDriver>();
            db.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            db.BatchSize = 1500;
            db.LogSqlInConsole = false;
            db.PrepareCommands = true;
            db.ConnectionReleaseMode = ConnectionReleaseMode.AfterTransaction;
            db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
        })
            .SetProperty(Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "web")
            .SetProperty(Environment.UseSecondLevelCache, "true")
            .SetProperty(Environment.ShowSql, "true")
            .SetProperty(Environment.PrepareSql, "true")
            .Cache(c =>
            {
                c.UseQueryCache = true;
                c.Provider<RtMemoryCacheProvider>();
                c.DefaultExpiration = 1440;
            }).SessionFactory().GenerateStatistics();

        HbmMapping mapping = GetMappings();
        cfg.AddDeserializedMapping(mapping, "AppName");
        SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(cfg);
        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static HbmMapping GetMappings()
    {
        var mapper = new ModelMapper();

        mapper.AddMappings(typeof (UserMap).Assembly.GetTypes());
        HbmMapping mapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
        return mapping;
    }
}
```

Here is a neat little bit for managing SignalR dependencies with Castle. You may want to give this a try just for giggles.

```
  public class SignalRDependencyResolver : Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.DefaultDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

    public SignalRDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        if (container == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        }
        _container = container;
    }

    public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return TryGet(serviceType) ?? base.GetService(serviceType);
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return TryGetAll(serviceType).Concat(base.GetServices(serviceType));
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    private object TryGet(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<object> TryGetAll(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            Array array = _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
            return array.Cast<object>().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Put this in global asax before you set your controller factory

```
 // SignalR
        _container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof(IHub)).LifestyleTransient());
        SignalRDependencyResolver signalRDependencyResolver = new SignalRDependencyResolver(_container);
        Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalRDependencyResolver;
```

Comment: I will try this approach to managing the session, maybe it will solve the issue. So in my repository classes I should inject ISessionManager and call _sessionManager.OpenSession() in my constructor?

Comment: Implementing your approach works great but still am having the same problem during OnDisconnected method. I get a null object error on this line: `if (CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(_sessionFactory))`. Debugging shows that my _sessionFactory is not null, so I'm unsure the problem still.

Comment: Set your context to web Environment.CurrentSessionContextClass, "web" in your nhibernate configuration.

Comment: You are going to make me create something using SignalR now arent you. LOL

Comment: I am a little curious about LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient() why does LifeStylePerWebRequest not work?

Comment: I've already set the CurrentSessionContextClass to "web" and still the problem persists. If I don't use HybridPerWebRequestTransient() then I get the error described [here](http://www.leniel.net/2013/01/signalr-ondisconnected-task-and-dependency-injection-with-castle.windsor-hybrid-lifestyle.html) where HttpContext is null during the scope of the SignalR Hub

Comment: Please update your question with any code changes so we can see what you have.